How can I load CSV into Memgraph Cloud?
I'm currently using Memgraph Cloud, and I have a very large graph that I need to import. I've tried converting the graph to a .csv file, but I'm encountering an error in the query when attempting to import it.
LOAD CSV from this question doesn't work for me.
Is it possible to import a local .csv file into Memgraph Cloud directly

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Memgraph Cloud doesn't have access to local filesystems, but if you are able to upload your file to a remote address with a public URL, you can use LOAD CSV from URL. Here are the docs explaining the syntax of the clause: https://memgraph.com/docs/data-migration/csv#load-csv-clause-syntax
